# How I know if a SelectionSorterWeightFactory is used

Tags: java, sorting, optaplanner

In the **optaplanner-quarkus-vehicle-routing-quickstart** example there is an implementation of the interface `SelectionSorterWeightFactory`. I don´t see any annotation or configuration that refer to it, but viewing the solution is in use. There isn't a .xml solver configuration.

Can do You help me to kwon where and how to configure?

I implement my own (same but with my own fields names), where the Customer is Fact. The order of the customers on each vahicle in the solution, isn't correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nANU.png)

The numbers of the pins are the solution order, but the correct (using that numbers) is: 1,2,3,6,5,4